# Is there any support in JDK6 and Spring 4.1.8 for XSL processing with Xpath version 2.0?

Tags: spring, xslt, xpath-2.0, xpath-1.0, jdk6

I am trying to achieve XML - XSLT transformation. For that I am using **JDK 6** and **Spring 4.1.8**. From the code I see **XsltPayloadTransformer** compiles **XSL** file and then transforms **XML** data file. But however my **XSL** uses **XPath V2** and It seems that **JDK6** doesn't support it. So is there any way I can still use **XSL with XPath v2.0**. Is there any support by **Spring** or do I need to degrade my **XPATH version** to **1.0** ??

Comment: I don't believe it's a matter of JDK. For XSLT / XPath support, it is usually an external library (e.g. Xalan or Saxon).

Comment: XSL using XPath 2.0 is usually simply XSLT 2.0 and the Sun/Oracle JDK does not support XSLT 2.0 as it uses an internalized version of Apache Xalan which is an XSLT 1.0 processor. In the Java world XSLT 2.0 support is available using Saxon 9, you have the choice between the open source version HE and the commercial versions PE and EE. The lastest version is 9.7 and according to http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/about/installationjava/prerequisites.html works with JDK 1.6.

Comment: Thanks a lot MartinHonnen and potame.
So bottom line is that I cant use Xalan because java already uses same and it does not support Xpath 2. So I have no choice but to go with Saxon.

Comment: @Zebronix_777, And this is a **good** choice :)